# Using Moran's I test for spatial autocorrelation on residuals from logistic mixed model?

Tags: r, autocorrelation

I know that tests using Moran's I are not appropriate for binary outcome variables, but can I use that test on the residuals from a logistic mixed model to see if spatial dependence is unaccounted for?

Different sources online state conflicting things about this and so I've been left unsure if this is appropriate or not as the residuals for logistic are estimated.

If it is not acceptable, what is the accepted way for testing for spatial autocorrelation in the residuals of a logistic mixed model?

I seek any references to specific R packages or Stata code that can perform such tests.